Keyboard stops responding when I connect my headset
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 on my Dell Inspiron 7580 laptop. I have an external keyboard and also a Logitech Zone Wireless 2 headset, which is wireless, but uses a USB dongle. Every time I connect the headset to the computer, the keyboard stops responding. If I wait some time and restart the app I was using (for example, Google Chrome), the keyboard usually goes back to normal. But it's annoying because it happens every time I turn the headset off and on.
I have the impression that the multimedia controls on the headset may be interfering. It seems that the headset is also identified somehow as a "keyboard" and the active app switches devices or something like that. Is that possible?
Any way to fix or investigate the issue further?
The output of lsusb is the following:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:301d Dell Computer Corp. Dell Universal Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2734 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB2734
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:0100 VIA Labs, Inc. USB 2.0 BILLBOARD             
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:4010 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:2501 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard and mouse dongle
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0c45:671f Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0424:274c Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub Controller
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 046d:0af0 Logitech, Inc. Zone 950
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5734 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) USB5734

The output of xinput list is the following:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DP-2                                      id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell Universal Receiver Mouse        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell Universal Receiver Consumer Control id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell KM632 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Consumer Control  id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Dell Dell KM632 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse   id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL08A6:00 06CB:CCA8 Touchpad            id=21   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL08A6:00 06CB:CCA8 Mouse               id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=27   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell Universal Receiver              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell Universal Receiver System Control   id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell KM632 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse   id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell KM632 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse System Control    id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=23   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=24   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=25   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=26   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DP-2                                      id=28   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell Universal Receiver Consumer Control id=29   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell Dell KM632 Wireless Keyboard and Mouse Consumer Control  id=30   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Zone 950 Consumer Control        id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech Zone 950                         id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]

Thanks!
